# What is the best way to view Wikipedia offline on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation

I'd like to view most articles of Wikipedia while I'm offline. I understand that it doesn't have to be or probably could be all articles, but a good subset would be nice.

Comment: if you only want specific pages, try [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/) or [Read It Later](http://readitlaterlist.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the Wikipanion free version on my iPad and there's a Wikipanion Plus available that supports offline viewing.  I'm happy with Wikipanion on my iPad and iPhone.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

[AllofWikiOffline](http://www.brilliantish.com/allofwiki/) app is the best I have seen and has reasonable update pricing if your offline copy needs updating in the future.

Comment: +1 Because it is a great app... and happens to be made by former colleagues of mine. :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of an app called "Wiki Offline" for iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch, and Mac. It provides the whole text of Wikipedia for offline consumption (images and tables can be imported for individual articles if you have an internet connection).

It is a very mature, highly rated product, with experience enhancements like tabbed browsing, a read-later queue, bookmarks/folders, customizable fonts, etc.

The other two "competing apps" are AllofWiki Offline and Encyclopedia. I encourage you to check out all of them.

[Wiki Offline](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wiki-offline-a-wikipedia-experience/id378348813?mt=8)

[All of Wikipedia](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/all-of-wikipedia-offline/id364878448?mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like [minipedia](http://minipedia.mobi) the best. It is available for both [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id473512078?pt=356848&at=1l3vpXa&ct=sx&mt=8) and Android and works completely offline after an initial download.

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded and access the whole wikipedia offline by following a tutorial given here(using kiwix) -  http://www.superpctricks.com/2013/10/download-entire-wikipedia-and-access-it.html

Comment: How did you get the result running on an iPad?

Answer (score -1):

Try the kiwix app! It's free and open source.